# samba - remote connection

Tags: samba

I have a samba-server. Can connect to it from my local network with no problem.
Can see that 139 and 445 port are opened. Site "speed-tester.info" also tells me that these ports are opened.
BUT when I scan my server nmap doesnt show me these ports!

have this string in smb.conf, so samba should listen external interface:

```
interfaces = lo0 msk*
```

I tried to add "\\89.179.246.174\disk_1" to my network in windows 7 but it failed.
Please help. What is wrong?

Comment: Which operation system is your Samba running on? -- Are you sure your actual interface names are following the 'msk*' convention? -- You should list all interfaces with the `ifconfig -s -a` command (on Linux). The interface/device names then are in the leftmost column.

Comment: I have FreeBSD.
I met somewhere 'msk*' during my search for solution to my problem.
Of course my interface is 'msk0' and I tried using it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was tired trying to connect my samba shares to my pc remotely.
So I found for myself 2 other solutions:

- Use expandrive (binds drive to explorer over ssh, but ssh slows down connection)
- Use hamachi

pipitas, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First, your line `interfaces = lo0 msk*` does not look right to me. I've never come across an OS that names its NIC devices with a 'msk*' convention.

Second, get aware of the correct syntax for the `interfaces = ...` statement in *smb.conf*. Here is my summary of it:

- `...` may hold one or several network interface names
- `...` may hold one or several IP addresses
- `...` may hold one or several hostnames
- `...` may hold one or several IPaddress/netmask pairs
- `...` may hold one or several broadcast/netmask pairs
- `...` may hold a mixture of all of the above

More details to be found in `man smb.conf`. Assuming that 89.179.246.174 is the address of your Samba server, the following should do what you want:

`interfaces = lo0 89.170.246.174`